# Storing replaced value into another array from an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I loop with a for in loop that loops through the object to find the key and value.

```
house: {
  john: {
       love_off: "mary"
  }
}
```

My for in loop returns:

```
 for ( var key in house.john) {
     house.john[key.replace("_off","") = house.john[key];
 }
```

It returns a copy of the original array long with:

```
house: {
      john: {
           love: "mary"
           love_off: "mary"
      }
    }
```

How do I just get `"love": "mary"` from the object and add it to array that needs to be returned?

Comment: You need to replace the `love_off` pair with the new `love` pair?

Comment: No array appears at `javascript` at Question. Is resulting object expected result? Are you trying to get the new property and value?

Comment: I am just trying to get the new property and value. I misspoke. I apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `delete` statement in order to delete the old property.

**The delete operator removes a property from an object.**

```js
var object={
  "house": {
     "john": {
       "love_off": "mary"
     }
  }
}
 for ( var key in object.house.john) {         
     object.house.john[key.replace("_off","")] = object.house.john[key];
     if(object.house.john.hasOwnProperty(key))
         delete object.house.john[key];
 }
console.log(object);
```

Comment: might need to check if the property exists first

Comment: suggestion...use hasOwnProperty() ... value of property could be falsy but still exist. And would check before modifications

Comment: @charlietfl, yes, you're right. `hasOwnProperty` is better choice in this situation.

Comment: @charlietfl _"suggestion...use hasOwnProperty()"_ Interesting. If recollect correctly, have received two different comments recently suggesting to use or not use `in` operator. Is the a Question that you are aware of that addresses difference between `in` operator and `.hasOwnProperty()`?

Comment: @guest271314 simply to check if key is enumerable

Comment: This one is close to the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If interpret Question correctly, you can use `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()` with `.replace()`

```
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/_off(?=":)/, ""));
```

Comment: Good answer!! But check that could be multiple properties with "_off" and with the method `String.prototype.replace()` only the first occurrence will be replaced

Comment: @YosvelQuintero The `RegExp` can be adjusted. Did not consider objects other than at OP before posting Answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var myArray= [] 
for ( var key in object.house.john) {         
     object.house.john[key.replace("_off","")] = object.house.john[key];
     delete object.house.john[key];
     myArray.push(object.house.john);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all Object keys with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Than make the replacement and the most important is to delete the old key property.

Code example:

```js
var obj = {house: {john: {love_off: "mary"}}};

Object.keys(obj.house.john).forEach(function (k) {
  obj.house.john[k.replace('_off', '')] = obj.house.john[k];
  delete obj.house.john[k];
});

console.log(obj);
```